# Grails domain property defaultValue does not set

Tags: grails, grails-orm

IN the domain I have the following instructions for the status property

```
static mapping={
    status defaultValue="NNE"
}

static constraints={
   status(nullable:false, inList:["NNE","NMO","NJE"])
}
```

But when I create a new instance of the domain object, the status is null rather than set to the default.

```
def instance=new Ticket();
println instance.status;// this is NULL instead of the default "NNE"
```

Is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: Not working either for me in Grails 3 and MySQL. Defaultvalue is correctly set when inserting a row outside of Grails. In Grails the value is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not suppose to be the case. `defaultValue` is a hint for the database constraint (`mapping` influences the database schema) and not the domain class itself. If you want a default value then set a default on the property. For example:

```
class TheClass {
  String status = 'DEFAULTHERE'
  ...
}
```